# update the particular entry with appropriate values in a given file

Tags: bash, shell

How can i update the particular entry with appropriate values in a given file,

Let say i have a file name hello.conf,

```
/agent/process="starthelloJava",start="/opt/starthello.sh",start_dir="/opt/hello",start_args=""
/agent/process="stophelloJava",stop="/opt/stophello.sh",stop_dir=/opt/hello",stop_args="",stop_timeout="30"
```

update the `starthelloJava` with

```
start_args="-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/"
```

output

```
/agent/process="starthelloJava",start="/opt/starthello.sh",start_dir="/opt/hello",start_args="-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/"
```

empty the `start_args` of process `starthelloJava`

```
/agent/process="starthelloJava",start="/opt/starthello.sh",start_dir="/opt/hello",start_args=""
/agent/process="stophelloJava",stop="/opt/stophello.sh",stop_dir=/opt/hello",stop_args="",stop_timeout="30"
```

The way i'm doing is long step's i'm rewriting the entire file, based on the input.

This is my apprach which is not efficient

```
cp hello.conf hello.conf_bak
remove entry first
cat /opt/CSCObac/agent/conf/agent.conf_bak | grep -v /opt/starthello.sh  > hello.conf
echo "/agent/process=\"starthelloJava\",start=\"/opt/starthello.sh\",start_dir=\"/opt/hello\",start_args=\"-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/\" >> hello.conf
```

Comment: I don't see any alternatives, unless you can guarantee the lengths will always agree (Murphy _will_ ensure they aren't when you've already forgotten about it). Perl has "inplace munging of files", check `perlrun(1)`, and I believe GNU `sed(1)` does also (they do write a temprary file and rename at the end).

Comment: @the patter is fixed only /agent/process="",start="",start_dir="" the value is fixed for only start and start_dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set -- '-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/'
sed -i -r "s!(.*starthelloJava.*=).*!\1\"$1\"!" hello.conf
```

or to empty the value

```
set -- ''
sed -i -r "s!(.*starthelloJava.*=).*!\1\"$1\"!" hello.conf
```